# Group by name on same row excluding NULL values

Tags: mysql, group-by

### I have a table with these rows:

```
name                |    id1      |    id2
-------------------------------------------------
aaa                 |   NULL      |     10
aaa                 |     4       |    NULL
```

I'd like to have this result:

```
-------------------------------------------------
name                |    id1      |    id2
-------------------------------------------------
aaa                 |   4         |     10
```

How can I do to obtain the expected result?

Comment: Note that this kind of situation can sometimes be symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: @Strawberry I absolutely agree with you, I'm trying to make up for choices not made by me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `aggregation max()/min()` with `group by`

```
select name, max(id1) as id1, max(id2) as id2
from tablename
group by name
```